# return data from Database to View?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2012, return

I have a class in my project where i read all Data from my Database, but is this the best way to just return them?

I used a Datatable for that purpose.

```
DataTable entries= new DataTable();

try
{
    sql_connection.Open();

    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from test", sql_connection);

    adapter.Fill(entries);
}
catch(Exception ex) {}
```

and in my View i add them to my ListView:

r is my result class, just to let you know.

```
for (int i = 0; i < r.entries.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ListViewItem data = new ListViewItem(r.entries.Rows[i][0].ToString());
    data.SubItems.Add(r.entries.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    data.SubItems.Add(r.entries.Rows[i][2].ToString());
    listView_d.Items.Add(data);
}
```

Is this a good way or is there a better way to do that?

My Form class does not know the System.Data or MySQL Namespace.

Comment: So you don't really have a problem, you just want to know if your code is/looks good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There should always be an abstraction between 3 layers such as Presentation (UI), Middle (Business) layer and Data (Access) layer.

During a 'GET' from data base, the return type should be a database entity say X. Now, your middle layer convert 'x' into Business object (say 'B') and finally the code behind does convert it to UI object (say 'U').


If you don't have a business layer, create a business object(if its Employee data, then create a class named 'Employee') and return the instance to code behind.

It is always a well-appreciated practice.
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but why is it like that and what is the advantage? I have one class that is doing all database operations like delete, add, search and so on and a class that is returning the data to the View. It would be nice if you could tell me for example related to my project and what you think about the way i am doing it actually.

Comment: @user3438236 - Assume you have a single class to hold values from database and UI, when you want to change the field that is bound to UI, then you need to change this class. Again, if the database schema has changed, you would need to edit the same class again. This is why OOPS force you to have abstraction. Give a class , single responsibility. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should return customised special objects that map your identity.